# I am a dreamer, who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I'm created by a man,
> But I'm still only a story to mankind,
> A horror story for if I awaken,
> Once I will return,
> And if you take a look at me, you'll lose your mind,
>
> I like the ocean,
> I am a dreamer,
> That still sleeps,
> I  am ... a monster.

**Question**: Can you guess who I am?

Comment: Any clue please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are

> Ctulhu

```
I'm created by a man,

But I'm still only a story to mankind,
```

> Ctulhu is a fictional character created by the man H. P. Lovecraft

```
A horror story for if I awaken,

Once I will return,
```

> In the short story, "The Call of Cthulhu", it is known that he will eventually return.

```
And if you take a look at me, you'll lose your mind,
```

> Looking at him will make the viewer insane, according to the story.

```
I like the ocean,

I am a dreamer,

That still sleeps,

I am ... a monster.
```

> Ctulhu is a monster sleeping in the ocean.

Comment: Just curious to know how did you find it out? Which part of the puzzle enlightened you?

Comment: Omy, I believe you must know him? :) 
I hoped it would take a bit longer, which part was it that gave you the clue?

Comment: @Decypher A horror monster, that lives in the sea, and if you look at him you go insane? Any single one of these clues would have pointed at the right answer, but all of them is just overwhelmingly obvious, which is why I downvoted the question.

Comment: I thought of answering this as **Godzilla** :/

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Yorith, the oldest dreamer ?

Because ...

> You're part of the fictional deities created by HP Lovecraft

Your love for oceans is explained by

> Where you live : the planet Yilla, an ocean planet.

Looking at you makes one lose his mind because

> of your hypnotic abilities.